# Doubt in the expression of partition function of a general canonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, partition-function

Suppose we have a system $S$ connected to a bath $B$. The combined system forms a microcanonical ensemble.
Suppose the energy of the combined system is $E_T$.
So, $E_S+E_B=E_T$.
The probability of finding the system $S$ in energy $E$ (or probability of finding a microstate of system corresponding to energy E) is
$\rho(E)=$ Probability of finding the bath in energy $(E_T-E)\;\alpha\;\Omega_B(E_T-E)$
$\displaystyle\implies \rho(E)\;\alpha\;\Omega_B(E_T-E)\tag{1}$
We consider bath to be huge and the system $S$ forms a tiny part of the combined system. So, $E<<E_B$. This means $E_T\approx E_B$
So, $(1)$ becomes
$\displaystyle\rho(E)\;\alpha\;\Omega_B(E_B-E)\tag{2}$
As $E$ is small, so we can do the Taylor expansion of the above expression around $E_B$ and retain only the first order terms.
Finally we get, $\displaystyle\rho(E)=Ce^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}\tag{3}$
Here $C$ is the normalization constant.
We can find $C$ as follows
$\displaystyle\sum_E\rho(E)=1=\sum_{\text{(All possible microstates)}}e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}=C\sum_E\Big(\sum_{\text{(All possible microstates with energy E)}}e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}\Big)=C\sum_E\Omega(E)e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}\tag{4}$
We can define the partition function as
$\displaystyle Z=\frac{1}{\sum_E\Omega(E)e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}}\tag{5}$
So, $\displaystyle\rho(E)=\frac{e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}}{Z}\tag{6}$

**Doubt**

1. $\rho(E)$ by definition is $\frac{\Omega(E)}{\sum_E\Omega(E)}$
   This is the probability of finding the sytem in macrostate $E$ or in other words, we can say that it is the probability of finding the system in a microstate corresponding to energy $E$ out of all the possible microstates that corresponds to different energies.
   In $(4)$, on the $RHS$ why we are **summing over all the possible microstates**. I think that by the definition it should be just **summing over all the energies E (macrostates)**.
   Then $\displaystyle Z=\frac{1}{\sum_{E}e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}}$
   I don't know what am I missing. Because in all the books, in partition function there is summing over all the possible microstates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of finding the system $S$ in a particular **micro**state $\mu$ which has energy $\epsilon(\mu)$ is
$$\mathrm{Prob}(\mu) = \frac{\Omega_B\big(E-\epsilon(\mu)\big)}{\Omega_{tot}}$$
where $\Omega_B(E)$ is the number of **micro**states of the bath with energy $E$ and $\Omega_{tot}$ is the total number of **micro**states of the system+bath.  We then have
$$\log\big[\mathrm{Prob}(\mu)\big] = \log\big[\Omega_B\big(E-\epsilon(\mu)\big)\big] - \log\big[\Omega_{tot}\big]$$
$$\approx \log\big[\Omega_B(E)/\Omega_{tot}\big] - \underbrace{\frac{\Omega_B'(E)}{\Omega_B(E)}}_{\equiv 1/kT} \epsilon(\mu)$$
$$\implies \mathrm{Prob}(\mu) = C  e^{-\epsilon(\mu)/kT}$$

That is, the probability of the **micro**state $\mu$ is equal to some constant $C$ times the usual Boltzmann factor.  To determine the constant $C$, we require that the sum of the probabilities of all of the **micro**states is equal to $1$, yielding
$$C = 1/Z, \qquad Z= \sum_{\mu} e^{-\epsilon(\mu)/kT}$$

It is true that for many of those microstates, $\epsilon(\mu)$ will be the same.  As a result, we could re-write this by summing over all system **energies** $\mathcal E$  and weighting each factor by the number of microstates with that energy $g(\mathcal E)$:
$$Z = \underbrace{\sum_\mu e^{-\epsilon(\mu)/kT}}_{\text{sum over microstates}} = \underbrace{\sum_\mathcal E g(\mathcal E) e^{-\mathcal E/kT}}_{\text{sum over energies}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read your answer. I still have some doubt. So, basically the system and bath are connected such that energy of the overall system is constant ($E_T$). If the system has energy $E$, then the bath has energy $E_T-E$. So, probability of finding the system in energy $E$ is same as probability of finding the bath in energy $E_T-E$ which is equal to $\frac{\Omega_B(E_T-E)}{\Omega_B^{tot}}$. Now, probability of finding the system in energy $E$ is same as probability of finding that microstate of system that is associated with energy E out of all the possible microstates.

Comment: i.e, $\frac{\Omega_{system}(E)}{\Omega_{system}^{tot}}$. But you are using $Prob(\mu)$ as probability of choosing a particular microstate having $\epsilon(\mu)$ out of total possible microstate in your first equation. But I somehow getting the impression that the development of canonical ensemble formulation suggests that instead of using $Prob(\mu)$ we should use $Prob(E)$ in the your first equation in the answer because $Prob_{system}(E)=Prob_{bath}(E_T-E)$

Comment: *"Now, probability of finding the system in energy  is same as probability of finding that microstate of system that is associated with energy E out of all the possible microstates.*"  This incorrect. The probability of finding the system with energy $E$ is equal to the probability of finding the system in **any** of the microstates with energy $E$ - which is given by the probability of finding the system in **one** of those microstates ($e^{-\mathcal E/kT}$) multiplied by the number of microstates with that energy ($g(\mathcal E)$).

Comment: In my answer, probabilities are associated with microstates, not with energies. If you want to compute the probability of a particular *energy*, then you can simply add up the probabilities of all of the microstates with that energy as said above to yield $g(\mathcal E)e^{-\mathcal E/kT}=e^{-(\mathcal E-TS)/kT} = e^{-F/kT}$, where $g \equiv e^{S/k}$ and $F=\mathcal E-TS$ is the Helmholtz energy.

Comment: *"$\rho(E)$ by definition is $\frac{\Omega(E)}{\sum_E\Omega(E)}$       
This is the probability of finding the sytem in macrostate $E$"* This is wrong. You are appealing to the microcanonical probability distribution, but that no longer applies to the system alone. You need to include the microstates of the bath. The probability of finding the system with energy $E$ is $\Omega_{sys}(E)\Omega_B(E_T-E)/\Omega_{tot}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for healthy discussion. I understand that there is problem only in the defnition. I just have one small doubt. Suppose we have a dice. The probability of dice being in odd number state (can be regarded as macrostate) is 1/2 (=(1+1+1)/6). So the dice can be in either 1,3 or 5 out of total 6 possibilities. In canonical ensemble case, if the (system+bath) is a microcanonical ensemble with total energy $E_T$. So if the system has energy $E$ then the bath will have energy $E_T-E$. If we consider energy of system and bath to be the two sets of random variables.

Comment: Then probability of system to have energy $E$ is same as probability of bath to have energy $E_T-E$. If use the analogy of the dice. We can regard the above probability as probability of the system to be in microstate associated with energy E, so this suggests that we are summing over macrostates not microstates. Can you please tell where my argument is false. I have read all your replies, but this confusion is still unclear to me. Can you please help?

Comment: @Iti I don't know how to explain it more clearly than I already have. You are saying that $\rho(E) = \Omega(E)/\sum_{E'}\Omega(E')$. The denominator of that expression is simply the total number of microstates of **any** energy which are accessible to the system, while $\Omega(E)$ is the number of microstates of the system with energy $E$.  This is **not true**. That probability distribution comes from the *microcanonical* ensemble, where the probability is simply proportional to the number of microstates. In the canonical ensemble, the probability that the system occupies any particular [...]

Comment: [...] **microstate** is proportional to $e^{-E/kT}$, where $E$ is the energy of that microstate. The exact probability is $e^{-E/kT}/ Z$, where $Z= \sum_{microstates} e^{-E/kT}$ and the sum over **microstates** (not energies!) is necessary in order for the total probability of all of the microstates to add up to 1.

Comment: @Iti If you wish to sum over *energies*, then you need to weight each term by the number of microstates of the system with that energy - that's the second summation I wrote in my last line, $Z=\sum_\mathcal E g(\mathcal E)e^{-\mathcal E/kT}$.